# Targeting the content of a field with a data-id tag

Tags: jquery

EDITED to include HTML element on page I'm trying to target...

I'm trying to target the contents of an input field on a page, which has a `data-id` tag (`FORENAME` in the code example).

If I put in a fixed string variable into my code (i.e. set `var fieldValue = "dave"`, it works as expected - I'm just having trouble adding the contents to the variable.

Thanks in advance.

```
<div >
        <input aria-labelledby="TribalTech_EBS_Agent5_Models_Page_Controls_StaticTextModel_1100013026_DISP_FIRST_NAME " class="Primary form-control" data-id="FORENAME" data-val="true" data-val-length="First Name - The field value must be a string with a maximum length of 50" data-val-length-max="50" data-val-required="First Name - A value is required" id="DataModel_DataLinks_Dummy__Data_0__Items_FORENAME__Value" name="DataModel.DataLinks[Dummy].Data[0].Items[FORENAME].Value" tabindex="0" type="text" value="" />
        <input id="DataModel_DataLinks_Dummy__Data_0__Items_FORENAME__OriginalItem_Value" name="DataModel.DataLinks[Dummy].Data[0].Items[FORENAME].OriginalItem.Value" type="hidden" value="" />
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-id=FORENAME]').change(function() {
    validateStuff();
  });
});

function validateStuff() {
  var fieldValue = $('[data-id="FORENAME"]').attr("content"); // this is the issue

  if (fieldValue == "") {
    alert("You must enter a value");
  } else {
    if (fieldValue == "brian" || fieldValue == "simon") {
      alert("Hooray!  Valid entry in field");
    } else {
      alert("This is invalid input");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if attr("content") is missng it's return null not empty("") so check both  condition .

Comment: Can you please edit the question to show the HTML of the element you want to target/read from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's missing quotes here `[data-id=FORENAME]`. Also, you should use `$('[data-id="FORENAME"]').val()` instead:

```js
(function() {
   "use strict";
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('[data-id="FORENAME"]').change(function() {
         validateStuff();
      });
   });

   function validateStuff() {
      var fieldValue = $('[data-id="FORENAME"]').val();
      console.log(fieldValue);
      if (fieldValue == "") {
         alert("You must enter a value");
      } else {
         if (fieldValue == "brian" || fieldValue == "simon") {
            alert("Hooray!  Valid entry in field");
         } else {
            alert("This is invalid input");
         }
      }
   }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-id="FORENAME">
```